# Auto create Jenkins jobs and update configs from source code repo - GitHub

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

I wanted to setup a single source of truth to my Jenkins running in different DC's (Data Centers), so I converted all my jenkins jobs to `pipeline jobs - Jenkinsfile` taken from Github repo.

I'm looking for a method to `create/delete/update Jenkins jobs in UI`, for the multiple Jenkins running in different DC's automatically. so I am looking to auto `create/delete` jobs in all Jenkins upon updating the Job configurations in the GitHub Repository.

Any recommendations or help for this workflow would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the [Jenkins Job DSL Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) it enables to generate Jobs via SCM managed code

Comment: @NoamHelmer when I create the jobs using Seed-Job (job-dsl plugin), ever time I run the seed-job, its updating all the job definitions of pipeline jobs, so I loose "Build with parameters" option, is there any way to resolve this issue? or Any idea to make seed-job more intelligent to create new jobs but not update old jobs definitions?

Comment: not quite sure i understand the issue, but the Job DSL (seed job) can create your pipelines with the parameters